# chrome remote interface client.Network is undefined

Tags: node.js, chrome-remote-debugging

I have the following code example from the CDP page

https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/wiki/Async-await-example

```
const CDP = require('chrome-remote-interface');

async function example() {
    let client;
    try {
        // connect to endpoint
        client = await CDP();
        // extract domains
     
        const {Network, Page} = client;
        // setup handlers
        Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
            console.log(params.request.url);
        });
        // enable events then start!
        await Network.enable();
        await Page.enable();
        await Page.navigate({url: 'https://github.com'});
        await Page.loadEventFired();
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    } finally {
        if (client) {
            await client.close();
        }
    }
}

example();
```

but when i run it with: node --inspect=9222 getLogs.js

it throws an error:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'requestWillBeSent' of undefined

I am completely new to this, so I don't know what else should I do, Network and Page they both are undefined.

Comment: Have you launched chrome like like this? 

"chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222"

Comment: no, I used node --inspect=9222 getLogs.js, where should I put your command?

Comment: well, in the terminal? If you are using windows, open cmd and put it there. If you are using linux/mac, instead of chrome.exe you would have to use whatever alias chrome uses for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `node getLogs.js`instead...

Found a similar issue on https://github.com/cyrus-and/chrome-remote-interface/issues/407